# SQL - How to flatten metric values grouped by category to a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to create a wide flat table to display different metrics for various categories. But with the below approach I get an exploded dataset.
What is a proper way to create a wide table where each metric has a single corresponding value? For example: (`TOTAL_CAT_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 = 372.8, CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 = 155.0, CAT_2_VALUE_SAMPLE_1=NULL, CAT_3_VALUE_SAMPLE_1=217.8`) etc.

Also, is there a way to reduce code duplication within the queries that differ only in the date period defined in WHERE condition?

```
WITH metrics_sample_1 AS (SELECT 
    CATEGORY,
    SUM(METRIC_VALUE * COEFF) AS TOTAL_CAT_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_1' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_2' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_2_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_3' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_3_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CAT_ID) AS CAT_ID_COUNT_SAMPLE_1
    FROM METRICS_DATA
    WHERE ACTION_DATE > (DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY CATEGORY
    ),

    metrics_sample_2 AS (SELECT 
    CATEGORY,
    SUM(METRIC_VALUE * COEFF) AS TOTAL_CAT_VALUE_SAMPLE_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_1' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_2' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_2_VALUE_SAMPLE_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_3' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_3_VALUE_SAMPLE_2,
    FROM METRICS_DATA
    WHERE ACTION_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -20, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())    
    GROUP BY CATEGORY
    )

SELECT * FROM metrics_sample_1
```

(When I select from both metrics_sample_1 and metrics_sample_2 the table gets exploded even more)

```
+------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| CATEGORY   | TOTAL_CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1| CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 | CAT_2_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 | CAT_3_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 |
+------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| CAT_1      | 155.0                     | 155.0                | 0.0                  | 0.0         |
| CAT_2      | NULL                      | 0.0                  | NULL                 | 0.0            |
| CAT_3      | 217.8                     | 0.0                  | 0.0                  | 217.8        |
+------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

I want to achieve the below result:

```
+----------------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| TOTAL_CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1  | CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1| CAT_2_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 | CAT_3_VALUE_SAMPLE_1 |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 372.8                       | 155.0               | NULL       |          217.8
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, then you don't need the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(METRIC_VALUE * COEFF) AS TOTAL_CAT_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_1' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_1_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_2' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_2_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY = 'CAT_3' THEN METRIC_VALUE * COEFF ELSE 0 END) AS CAT_3_VALUE_SAMPLE_1,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CAT_ID) AS CAT_ID_COUNT_SAMPLE_1
FROM METRICS_DATA
WHERE ACTION_DATE > DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE());
```