# How to concatenate string characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I want to concatenate the data in location column into one cell. I don't know if it's possible.

farmtable

| Id | Item | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Block C |
| 2 | Coffee | Block A |
| 3 | Coffee | Block B |
| 4 | Apple | Block B |

```
Select 
  Item,
  Location
From farmtable
Group By Item
```

Expected Result

| Id | Item | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Block C, Block B |
| 2 | Coffee | Block A, Block B |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846210/sql-how-to-flatten-metric-values-grouped-by-category-to-a-single-row

Comment: Upgrade your obsolete SQL Server version, then this task becomes a trivial `STRING_AGG` use case

Comment: As you're on express there's no reason to *not* upgrade your instance. Especially as 2014 is imminently running out of (extended) support.

Comment: Yes the links you guys provided was able to solve my problem. Thank you all